Qlik Replicate Web Console in Firefox
When accessing the Qlik Replicate Web Console using Firefox, I can't see the "Monitor" button in the upper-right corner inside a task. When using Edge or Chrome it works as supposed.
Edge:

Firefox:

When analyzing the website, I can see the button in Firefox hidden behind the next line:

Does anyone know how to fix this?
